# React being able to autofill a second input form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two forms in React like this:

```
 <Form.Input fluid label='H5 Port' name='hfivePortValue' value={hfivePortValue} placeholder='Enter H5 Port' onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
 <Form.Input fluid label='Titan Port' name='titanPortValue' value={titanPortValue} placeholder='Enter Titan Port' onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Is there a way that if the user enters a value in the first form.input, that it will autofill the 2nd input with that first input?

Also, would it be possible that if the user then wants to edit the 2nd input form, that it would not edit the 1st?

Comment: you can do like at
1. first set the state of both on change.
2. after that you have to take a state like isFocus: false for second one which will change when focus on second

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 different handlers for you inputs. On the first, when it is trigerred, it changes the value for the first and for the second input. For the second, it just changes the value for the second. Snippet below:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       h5: "",
       titan: ""
    }
  }
  handleH5Change = (e) => {
     this.setState({
        h5: e.target.value, titan: e.target.value
     })
  }
  handleTitanChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
        titan: e.target.value
     })
  }
  render() {
   return (
    <div>
       <input placeholder="Enter H5 Port" value={this.state.h5} onChange={this.handleH5Change} />
       <input placeholder="Enter Titan Port"value={this.state.titan} onChange={this.handleTitanChange} />
    </div>
   ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following solution.
1) separate change handlers
2) add a flag to mark if the second input has its own value then it will not be overriden by the first input

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [hfivePortValue, setHfivePortValue] = useState('');
  const [titanPortValue, setTitanPortValue] = useState('');
  const [titanHasOwnValue, setTitanHasOwnValue] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
    <Form.Input fluid label='H5 Port' name='hfivePortValue' value={hfivePortValue} placeholder='Enter H5 Port' onChange={(e) => {
      setHfivePortValue(e.target.value);
      if(!titanHasOwnValue) {
        setTitanPortValue(e.target.value);
      }
    }} />
    <Form.Input fluid label='Titan Port' name='titanPortValue' value={titanPortValue} placeholder='Enter Titan Port' onChange={(e) => {
      setTitanPortValue(e.target.value);
      setTitanHasOwnValue(Boolean(e.target.value));
    }} />
  </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Your React JSX is invalid. It will give the error `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.`

Comment: Tks, I just copied from the question. It is not intended to be ready to run since it is missing forminput